# Opening Rich Text Editor in custom field of Sitecore Content Editor

Tags: sitecore

I'm implementing a custom field in Sitecore for the Content Editor, and I need to be able to open the Rich Text editor and get the data from there. I'm not really sure where to look though, nor how to go about it.

Comment: Can you describe more about your control? What do you mean by that? It can mean many things in Sitecore...

Comment: Sorry. I'm creating a custom data type that will be used in the Content Editor (similar to what's described here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Creating%20a%20Composite%20Custom%20Field.aspx)

I want to have a button similar to the "Show Editor" button for Rich Text fields for items

Comment: Can you provide more details about why you need to do this? For example, why would a built-in Rich Text Editor field not suffice? It sounds like you need the functionality of a RTE but I'm not sure why or what beyond the RTE it is that you need.

Comment: Adding the Rich Text Field to the content editor only provides a box to render the content, but it's not editable. I don't know how to pop up the rich text editor itself, populate it with an item's content, and then retrieve the changes when the user clicks "Accept"

Comment: It sounds like you have permissions issues. You simply need to double-click on the content area or click the "Show Editor" button to pop it open.

Comment: Negative. I'm trying to create a completely custom control, so I'm adding the rich text control programmatically. Doing so though only adds the box to render the content, but doesn't come with buttons to launch the editor. This should happen via some sort of API call, but I'm not sure which one, nor what messages to look for to get the content back when the user is finished editing

Comment: Ok, I understand. My question was "why do you need to create a custom field?" What do you need beyond the out of the box RTE field that it doesn't give you that is forcing you to create your own field? I ask because creating a custom field type is a major job (lots of things to consider).

Comment: I'm exploring a way to have one field contain different content specific to a given device. For example, viewing a page on a desktop would have content A, while viewing on a mobile device would have content B. We don't want to create new items or new fields if we can keep everything together (not everything needs specific content). The idea is one field that holds content as XML for at least one device, and renders if available or uses the default device content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to decompile the Sitecore.Kernel DLL in order to figure this out.

First thing is to spin off a call from the `Context.ClientPage` object

So, for my situation:

```
switch (message.Name)
{
    case "richtext:edit":
        Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "EditText");
        break;
}
```

You will then need to have a method in your class with the same name as defined in the above `Start` method. Then, you either start the rich text control if the request isn't a postback, or handle the posted data

```
protected void EditText(ClientPipelineArgs args)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
    if (args.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (args.Result == null || args.Result == "undefined")
            return;
        var text = args.Result;
        if (text == "__#!$No value$!#__")
            text = string.Empty;
        Value = text;
        UpdateHtml(args); //Function that executes Javascript to update embedded rich text frame
    }
    else
    {
        var richTextEditorUrl = new RichTextEditorUrl
                                    {
                                        Conversion = RichTextEditorUrl.HtmlConversion.DoNotConvert,
                                        Disabled = Disabled,
                                        FieldID = FieldID,
                                        ID = ID,
                                        ItemID = ItemID,
                                        Language = ItemLanguage,
                                        Mode = string.Empty,
                                        Source = Source,
                                        Url = "/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/EditorPage.aspx",
                                        Value = Value,
                                        Version = ItemVersion
                                    };
        UrlString url = richTextEditorUrl.GetUrl();
        handle = richTextEditorUrl.Handle;
        ID md5Hash = MainUtil.GetMD5Hash(Source + ItemLanguage);
        SheerResponse.Eval("scContent.editRichText(\"" + url + "\", \"" + md5Hash.ToShortID() + "\", " +
                            StringUtil.EscapeJavascriptString(GetDeviceValue(CurrentDevice)) + ")");
        args.WaitForPostBack();
    }
```