# How to open and handle richtext editor in javascript in sitecore 6.5?

Tags: telerik, sitecore, sitecore6, richtext

I've been working on a custom field, which contains a list.
I have to be able to edit the selected item on the list in a richtext editor. (this is the only missing part).

I've read the topic on opening from c# code [Opening Rich Text Editor in custom field of Sitecore Content Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333617/opening-rich-text-editor-in-custom-field-of-sitecore-content-editor) .
This works nice for the "add" button, since i have to open the RTE empty(with default text...), but not for the Edit button.

My aproaches are:

- Somehow in the Edit button's message field `list:edit(id=$Target)` pass the selected index (like `list:edit(id=$Target,index=$SelectedIndex)`, but i don't know how to populate $SelectedIndex
- Somehow in the overridden `HandleMessage` method get the list's selected **index**. I'm able to get the selected **value** `Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientRequest.Form[ID of list]`, but thats alone not much of a help, since i won't be able to decide which one to edit if two listitem equals.
- Do the richtext editor opening and handling fully in javascript. As i saw at some script in content editor, i tried to do that, but i can't understand it clearly:

  *richtext editor url:*

  `var page = "/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/EditorPage.aspx";`

  *some params :*

  `var params = "?da=core&id&ed=" + id + "&vs=1&la=en&fld=" + id +  "&so&di=0&hdl=H14074466&us=sitecore%5cadmin&mo";`

  *and the part where i'm not sure:*

  `var result = scForm.browser.showModalDialog(page + params, new Array(window), "dialogHeight:650px; dialogWidth:900px;");`

  This way the RTE opens as expected (i guess i could get the selected index from javascript and pass it as a parameter later). However when i click ok, i get exception from EditorPage.js saveRichText function: `Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null`. Am i missing some parameter?

Either of the three aproaches is fine for me(also i'm open for new better ones) as soon as i'm able to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Tamas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to enter some javascript into the message:

```
list:Edit(id=$Target,index='+document.getElementById(ID of the select using $Target ).selectedIndex+')
```

this way i got the index in `HandleMessage`.

I'm waiting for better solutions now.